# Apply mask to image

Tags: c#, image-processing, imagesharp

I need to apply mask (`3x3`) to image manually by iterating through it and calculating new values for each pixel. My code seems to work, but there is an issue - new value might not be between 0 and 255, it can be higher or lower. Such values are not acceptable. And now I don't know how to correctly solve it.

Apparently normalization to 0-255 will work, but here I need to normalize whole set of values which are known after loop is finished. This means I need to iterate through entire image twice.

You can also rate my code, maybe something can be improved, and maybe it actually doesn't work correctly despite compiling and creating processed images.

```cs
        public Image<Rgba32> ApplyMask3x3(int[,] mask, Image<Rgba32> image)
        {
            Image<Rgba32> result = new Image<Rgba32>(image.Width, image.Height);

            for(int row = 0; row < image.Height; row++)
            {
                for(int col = 0; col < image.Width; col++)
                {
                    byte R = 0, G = 0, B = 0;

                    //temporary - forcefully throw new values to 0-255
                    int valR = ApplyMaskR3x3(col, row, image, mask); //code below
                    int valG = ApplyMaskG3x3(col, row, image, mask); //identical code as R but uses G attribute
                    int valB = ApplyMaskB3x3(col, row, image, mask); //identical code as R but uses B attribute
                    if (valR > 255) valR = 255;
                    if (valR < 0) valR = 0;
                    if (valG > 255) valG = 255;
                    if (valG < 0) valG = 0;
                    if (valB > 255) valB = 255;
                    if (valB < 0) valB = 0;

                    R = Convert.ToByte(valR);
                    G = Convert.ToByte(valG);
                    B = Convert.ToByte(valB); ;

                    result[col, row] = new Rgba32(R,G,B);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

```cs
private int ApplyMaskR3x3(int col, int row, Image<Rgba32> image, int[,] mask)
        {
            int a, b, c;
            int d, e, f;
            int g, h, i;

            if (col == 0 || row == 0)
                a = 0;
            else
                a = image[col - 1, row - 1].R * mask[0, 0];

            if (row == 0)
                b = 0;
            else
                b = image[col, row - 1].R * mask[0, 1];

            if (row == 0 || col == image.Width - 1)
                c = 0;
            else
                c = image[col + 1, row - 1].R * mask[0, 2];


            if (col == 0)
                d = 0;
            else
                d = image[col - 1, row].R * mask[1, 0];

            e = image[col, row].R * mask[1, 1];

            if (col == image.Width - 1)
                f = 0;
            else
                f = image[col + 1, row].R * mask[1, 2];


            if (col == 0 || row == image.Height - 1)
                g = 0;
            else
                g = image[col - 1, row + 1].R * mask[2, 0];

            if (row == image.Height - 1)
                h = 0;
            else
                h = image[col, row + 1].R * mask[2, 1];

            if (col == image.Width - 1 || row == image.Height - 1)
                i = 0;
            else
                i = image[col + 1, row + 1].R * mask[2, 2];

            return a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;
        }
```

Comment: If you are going to clamp to [0, 255], you can do it within the `ApplyMaskR3x3` method by returning 255 if sum>255, 0 if sum<0, sum otherwise.

Comment: Normalizing after applying the mask seems reasonable to me.  Is there a reason you can't iterate through the image a second time?  You can avoid iterating three times by saving the max and min values during the first iteration.

Comment: Btw the operation you are performing is called a Convolution.

Comment: The answer depends on 1) what kind of convolution you apply, 2) how severe the overshoot is, 3) what you do with the image next. (The options are global rescaling, clipping or changing to another pixel format.)

Comment: @FelixCastor I have honestly no limits how long it can take, but if image is big 2nd iteration might make it significantly longer. But if there is no other way I will just read values first, normalize, apply values on 2nd iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to make use of the `Filter` processor built in to ImageSharp

From your code sample you should be able to do this

```cs
public Image<Rgba32> ApplyMask3x3(int[,] mask, Image<Rgba32> image)
{
    var matrix = new ColorMatrix(
        mask[0,0],
        mask[0,1],
        mask[0,2],
        mask[1,0],
        mask[1,1],
        mask[1,2],
        mask[2,0],
        mask[2,1],
        mask[2,2]
    );
    image.Mutate(x=>x.Filter(matrix));
    return image;
}
```

replace `.Mutate()` with `.Clone()` if you actually need a 2nd image and don't want to mutate in place.

If you `Clone` you need to make sure that both source and output images are disposed of correctly otherwise you can end up causing memory issues.